# Can wine be made from citrus fruits?

Tags: fermentation, wine, citrus

Can wine be made from citrus fruits? They have sugar to feed the yeast. Or does the citric acid interfere with the fermentation process?

I'm familiar with limoncello, but that is made by soaking lemons in alcohol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. The U.S. [Code of Federal Regulations](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=27%3A1.0.1.1.2;cc=ecfr#se27.1.4_121) classes wine as grape wine, citrus wine, or fruit wine; as examples of labelling of citrus wine containing only one fruit it mentions orange wine and grapefruit wine.

However, the Wikipedia page on [fruit wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_wine#Orange_wine) notes that it's difficult to make, and it's normal for some of the citric acid to be neutralised.

Comment: The very keen brewer I used to work with mad an orange wine, but it had other fruit in it as well.  The orange flavour came through but the acid was diluted